# In ADF, can I filter a table using the SAP Table Connector (RFC Table Options) by subtracting days from the current date without dynamic content?

Tags: azure-data-factory, saprfc

I want to filter a SAP table by today's date minus a number of days using the RFC Table Options of the SAP Table Connector in Azure Data Factory. Normally I would use dynamic content in ADF to generate the date text (something like formatDateTime(adddays(utcNow(),-60),'yyyyMMdd')), but I am loading the RFC Table Options from a metadata model so the filter text needs to be static.

I am able to do a filter for today's date using sy-datum (example filter below), but I can't seem to add/subtract days from this date.

ENDDA GE sy-datum